# Can't use knp_pagination_render with KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: php, symfony, knppaginator

category-forum.html.twig :

```
{% extends "BISSAPForumBundle::layout-forum.html.twig" %}  
[...]
<section class="paginationContent">
                <a class="btn btn-primary right-flt creatThread" href="#">Créer un sujet</a>
                <div class="navigation">
                    {% set test = [88,99] %}
                    {{ knp_pagination_render(listTopics,'ForumBundle:Pagination:sliding_bissap.html.twig',test) }}
                </div>

</section>
[...]
```

I have this message :

**Unable to find template "ForumBundle:Pagination:sliding_bissap.html.twig" in BISSAPForumBundle:F:category-forum.html.twig at line 28.**

```
root@LinuxBissap:/var/www/Symfony/src/BISSAP/ForumBundle/Pagination# ll
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  2 sebastien sebastien 4096 août  21 00:36 ./
drwxrwxrwx 10 root      root      4096 août  21 00:36 ../
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sebastien sebastien 1387 août  21 00:36    sliding_bissap.html.twig*
```

Comment: try renaming `ForumBundle` with   `BISSAPForumBundle`. I think you need to move your template in a folder named `BISSAP/ForumBundle/esources/views/Pagination`

Comment: I moved it, now it's Ok...Thanks U - Merci

Comment: Hi @Bissap, i post my comment as an answer so you can accept it and close your question. Feel free yo upvote my answer if you retain it useful!

Comment: How Can I close my question? I'm beginner here !

Comment: Hi @Bissap if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1. Renaming ForumBundle with `BISSAPForumBundle`.
2. move your template in a folder named `BISSAP/ForumBundle/esources/views/Pagination`

Hope this help